# If a floating-point number is representable in my machine, will its inverse be representable in my machine?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

Given some initialized object `x` of type `double` that stores a positive value, I want to find the smallest `double` `v` such as `0 <= v < 1/x`.

It seems fairly obvious that I could write `double v = DBL_EPSILON;`, but, if `x` is big enough, could it happen that `v` end up being bigger than the real value 1/x because it's so small that cannot be represented in my machine?

In other words, and more precisely, if I have a positive real number x and an object `x1` of type `double` whose stored value represents x exactly, is it guaranteed that the value represented by `DBL_EPSILON` is less than the real number 1/x?

In case it is not guaranteed, how can I calculate the biggest value of type `double` that ensures that `DBL_EPSILON` is less than the real number 1/x?

Comment: If denormalized floating point is allowed, fractions can get much smaller than the inverse of the largest float.

Comment: On platforms compatible with the IEEE-754 floating-point standard, `DBL_EPSILON` is likely `0x1.0p-52`. Thus only for positive `x == x1 < 0x1.0p+52` will `DBL_EPSILON` be guaranteed to be less than 1/x.

Comment: `0.0` is representable but I bet `1/0.0` isn't unless you count NaN.

Comment: @tadman that's why I specify that x is a positive number.

Comment: There is no value smaller than `v=0` which fulfills `0<=v` and as long as `0<x<infinity` this will also fulfill `v<1/x`. `v=DBL_EPSILON` won't fulfill your inequality for any `x>1.0/DBL_EPSILON` (and `DBL_EPSILON` is larger than 0 anyway ...)

Comment: Not all fractional values are representable by a computer, similar to decimal can't accurately handle 1/3.

Comment: `DBL_EPSILON` doesn't mean what you seem to think it means.  It is not the smallest possible gap between representable `double` values, but rather the difference specifically between `1.0` and the next larger representable `double`.  The gaps between representable values vary with the magnitude of the values.

Comment: Can you please fix the problem description? For "I want to find the smallest double v such as 0 <= v < 1/x.", the answer is trivial and easy: `v = 0`. (This isn't nitpicking - I'm genuinely confused about what it is you want.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume `double` is IEEE 754 binary64.

> If a floating-point number is representable in my machine, will its inverse be representable in my machine?

Not necessarily, for two reasons:

1. The inverse might not be a floating-point number.

   For example, although 3 is a floating-point number, 1/3 is not.
2. The inverse might overflow.

   For example, the inverse of 2<sup>−1074</sup> is 2<sup>1074</sup>, which is not only larger than all finite floating-point numbers but more than halfway from the largest finite floating-point number, 1.fffffffffffffp+1023 = 2<sup>1024</sup> − 2<sup>971</sup>, to what would be the next one after that, 2<sup>1024</sup>, if the range of exponents were larger.
   So the inverse of 2<sup>−1074</sup> is rounded to infinity.

> Given some initialized object `x` of type `double` that stores a positive value, I want to find the smallest `double` `v` such as `0 <= v < 1/x`.

The *smallest* such  is always zero.
If you restrict it to be nonzero, it will always be the smallest subnormal floating-point number, 0x1p−1074, or roughly 4.9406564584124654 × 10<sup>−324</sup>, irrespective of  (unless  is infinite).
But perhaps you want the *largest* such  rather than the *smallest* such .

The *largest* such  is always either 1 ⊘  = fl(1/) (that is, the floating-point number nearest to 1/, which is what you get by writing `1/x` in C), or the next floating-point number closer to zero (which you can get by writing `nextafter(1/x, 0)` in C): in the default rounding mode, the division operator always returns the nearest floating-point number to the true quotient, or one of the two nearest ones if there is a tie.

You can also get the largest such  by setting the rounding mode with `fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD)` or `fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO)` and then just computing `1/x`, although toolchain support for non-default rounding modes is spotty and mostly they serve to shake out bugs in ill-conditioned code rather than to give reliable rounding semantics.

> It seems fairly obvious that I could write `double v = DBL_EPSILON;`, but, if `x` is big enough, could it happen that `v` end up being bigger than the real value `1/x` because it's so small that cannot be represented in my machine?

`1/x` is never rounded to zero unless  is infinite or you have nonstandard flush-to-zero semantics enabled (so results which would ordinarily be subnormal are instead rounded to zero, such as when  is the largest finite floating-point number 0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023).

But flush-to-zero aside, there are many values of  for which 1/ and fl(1/) = `1/x` is smaller than `DBL_EPSILON`.

For example, if  = 0x1p+1000 (that is, 2<sup>1000</sup> ≈ 1.0715086071862673 × 10<sup>301</sup>), then 1/ = fl(1/) = `1/x` = 0x1p−1000 (that is, 2<sup>−1000</sup> ≈ 9.332636185032189 × 10<sup>−302</sup>) is far below `DBL_EPSILON` = 0x1p−52 (that is, 2<sup>−52</sup> ≈ 2.220446049250313  × 10<sup>−16</sup>).
1/ in this case is a floating-point number, so the reciprocal is computed exactly in floating-point arithmetic; there is no rounding at all.
The largest floating-point number below 1/ in this case is 0x1.fffffffffffffp−1001, or 2<sup>−1000</sup> − 2<sup>−1053</sup>.

`DBL_EPSILON` (2<sup>−52</sup>) is not the smallest floating-point number (2<sup>−1074</sup>), or even the smallest normal floating-point number (2<sup>−1022</sup>).
Rather, `DBL_EPSILON` is the distance from 1 to the next larger floating-point number, 1 + 2<sup>−52</sup>, sometimes written ulp(1) to indicate that it is the magnitude of the least significant digit, or unit in the last place, in the floating-point representation of 1.

> In case it is not guaranteed, how can I calculate the biggest value of type `double` that ensures that `DBL_EPSILON` is less than the real number 1/x?

That would be `1/DBL_EPSILON - 1`, or 2<sup>52</sup> − 1.
But what do you want this number for?
Why are you trying to use `DBL_EPSILON` here?

Comment: I haven't read your answer yet but about your last question, I want to choose the biggest representable number of a right-open interval, where the size of the interval is an inverse multiplicative, so I take the boundary and substract epsilon making sure that epsilon is not bigger than the size of the interval; otherwise I will choose the left boundary of the interval.

Comment: @Peregring-lk Subtracting `DBL_EPSILON` is almost never an appropriate thing to do, and suggests you might not be clear on how floating-point arithmetic works.  If you're trying to get the next floating-point number closer to zero, you can use `nextafter`, but there are very few numbers `t`f or which `nextafter(t, 0)` coincides with `t - DBL_EPSILON`.  What are you really trying to do here?  Are you trying to implement interval arithmetic?

Comment: It's a maximization problem where the solution is related to intervals, among other restrictions. If I choose something not in specific intervals then I'm returning a non-feasible or non-optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of positive infinity is, of course, smaller than any positive rational number. Beyond that, even the largest finite floating point number has a multiplicative inverse well above the smallest representable floating point number of equivalent width, thanks to denormal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> If a floating-point number is representable in my machine, will its inverse be representable in my machine?

No. There is no specification that `1.0/DBL_MIN <= DBL_MAX` and `1.0/DBL_MAX <= DBL_MIN` both must be true. One is usually true.  With sub-normals, 1.0/sub-normal is often > `DBL_MAX`.

---

> Given some initialized object x of type `double` that stores a positive value, I want to find the smallest double v such as 0 <= v < 1/x.

This is  true as `v` could be zero unless for some large `x` like `DBL_MAX`, `1.0/x` is zero.  That is a possibility.   With sub-normals, that is rarely the case as `1.0/DBL_MAX` is representable as a value more than 0.

`DBL_EPSILON` has little to do with the above.  OP's issues are more dependent on `DBL_MAX, DBL_MIN` and is the `double` supports sub-normals.  Many FP encodings  about balanced where `1/DBL_MIN` is somewhat about `DBL_MIN`, yet C does not require that symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Floating point numbers are balanced around `1.0` to minimize the effect of calculating inverses, but this balance is not exact, ad the middle point for the exponent (the value `0x3fff...` fot the exponent, gives the same number of powers of two above and below `1.0`.  But the exponent value `0x4ffff...` is reserved for infinity and then nans, while the value `0x0000...` is reserved for denormals (also called subnormals)  These values are not normalized (and some architectures don't even implement them), but in those that implement, they add as many bits as the width of the mantissa as  powers of 2 in addition (but with with lower precision) to the normalized ones, in the range of
the negative exponents.  This means that you have a set o numbers, quite close to zero, for which when you compute their inverses, you always get infinity.

For doubles you have 52 more powers of two, or around  15 more powers of ten.  For `float`s, this is around 7 more powers of ten.

But this also means that if you calculate the inverse of a large number you'll always get a number different than zero.